# PHP time subtraction not functioning

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to display the time x started, the time x finished, and how long x took to complete. I have the start and end displaying correctly, but the following subtraction gives me a bonkers answer.

```
    // to unix timestamps for subtraction
    $startTime = strtotime($row['bp_rec_start']);
    $endTime = strtotime($row['bp_rec_end']);
    $timeTaken = $endTime - $startTime;

    //back to date formats
    $startTime = date('H:i',$startTime);
    $endTime = date('H:i',$endTime);
    $timeTaken = date('H:i',$timeTaken);
```

e.g. ( 01:24 - 01:23 = 07:01)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamps are *seconds since 1970*, each timestamp representing an **absolute** point in time. So `$endTime - $startTime` produces some point in time like `1975-04-12 07:01:52`. Printing the hour and minute part of that will of course print `07:01`. The timestamp itself though is the difference in seconds, so you can do:

```
echo "Difference: $timeTaken seconds";
```

You should of course look into [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) (look at the 3rd example).